# Cookies and subdomains

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Can a cookie be shared between two sites on the same top level domain? Say `www.example.com` and `secure.example.com` ?
We are looking into implementing a cache for non-secure content, and need to segregate secure content to another domain.
What parameters does the cookie need? I'm using asp.net

Comment: Note: This can cause [bugs or security issues](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/12412/396) depending on the cookie content.  [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9636857/328397)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use:

```
Response.Cookies("UID").Domain = ".myserver.com"
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to apply a cookie domain that can be shared across subdomains is to put it in your web.config:

```
<forms cookieDomain="example.com">
```

Comment: Yeah, the spec is quite annoying.  If you want to use example.com as your main domain, you can't then use static.example.com for your (cookieless) static files, and are forced to register another domain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but beware don't set same-named cookies in various subdomains, as the resulting cookie appears to be random; instead, set one cookie in the .maindomain.com only (not in any .sub.domain.com)