# Can subdomain.example.com set a cookie that can be read by example.com?

Tags: http, cookies, subdomain

I simply cannot believe this is quite so hard to determine.

Even having read the RFCs, it's not clear to me if a server at subdomain.example.com can set a cookie that can be read by example.com.

subdomain.example.com can set a cookie whose Domain attribute is .example.com.  RFC 2965 seems to explicitly state that such a cookie will not be sent to example.com, but then equally says that if you set Domain=example.com, a dot is prepended, as if you said .example.com.  Taken together, this seems to say that if example.com returns sets a cookie with Domain=example.com, it doesn't get that cookie back! That can't be right.

Can anyone clarify what the rules really are?

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108558/cookies-and-subdomains

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Yes.**

If you make sure to specify that the domain is .example.com, then *.example.com and example.com can access it.

It's that principle that allows websites that issue cookies when somebody goes to [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) to access cookies when someone leaves off the www, going to website.com.

EDIT: From the PHP documentation about cookies:

> domain The domain that the cookie is
> available. To make the cookie
> available on all subdomains of
> example.com then you'd set it to
> '.example.com'. The . is not required
> but makes it compatible with more
> browsers. Setting it to
> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) will make the cookie
> only available in the www subdomain.
> Refer to tail matching in the » spec
> for details.
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

And it's not unique to PHP.

Comment: -1 That's called a 301 redirect and doesn't properly reflect what the question is asking.

Comment: Evan, if you go to http://www.worldbreathday.org/, and then go to http://worldbreathday.org/, you'll note there is no redirection; and yet those two websites can still share cookies with each other. It's a well know phenomenon, look it up :)

Comment: @AaronYodaiken both links are broken now; cannot check :)