# Setting a cookie on a subdomain from an ajax request

Tags: cookies, subdomain

I have a webapp on www.example.com and an API on api.example.com.

The webapp makes ajax calls to the API.

Somewhere I need to put a cookie on api.example.com to keep sessions track.

To track my problem I've set test cookies on both subdomaines from the webapp and the api.
The webapp set a cookie on .exemple.com and the api set one on .exemple.com and another on api.exemple.com.
Cookies are set using Domain=.exemple.com only. No path, no HTTPOnly.

Note: In the end I need only one on api.exemple.com. But theses are for the tests.

Direct queries using my browser (Firefox 16) works fine.
Query on api: the two cookies are set and sent.
Query on www: the cookie is set and the two from the api is sent too. (Provided I query www after the api, of course).

Now, I clean the browser cookies and query www only.
Query on www: works fine, same as before.
Subquery on api, from www's ajax request: no cookies are sent. Set-Cookies does nothing. Using Firebug I see the cookies in the response. But no traces of them on subsequent requests or the page informations.

I event tried to enable the cookies log on Firefox. Absolutly no traces of the cookies from api, not even a reject notice.

In the end I only need a way to store one cookie on api. And for that, I quite open :)

Informations:
The two servers are NodeJS.
I've tried to set the cookie on the server side (Set-Cookie header), on the client side (document.cookies), manually using firebug.

Others posts I've checked with no solutions (And many others which I don't recall):

[setting cross-subdomain cookie with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713019/setting-cross-subdomain-cookie-with-javascript)

[Cookies and subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108558/cookies-and-subdomains)

[Can subdomain.example.com set a cookie that can be read by example.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089199/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Set the allow Credentials header on api

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

#### Use `withCredentials` for the request

```
$.ajax({
    url: a_cross_domain_url,
    xhrFields: { 
        withCredentials: true 
    }
});
```

Otherwise the `XMLHttpRequest` will **not** send the cookies, regardless of the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header.

#### Remove the wildcard on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
```

The wildcard `*` will not work. The browser will discard the response if `withCredentials` was set.

References:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/credentialedRequest.html

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank the merciful lord Ixbalanque, but mostly you, for this answer. That was a day lost to the vagaries or CORS and cookies.

Comment: I tried this, but still have same problem. I am setting CORS and xhr `withCredentials`. This is my cors: `'supportsCredentials' => true,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],`

Comment: save my day! Thanks @Alexandre

Comment: thanks, saved me a lot of nerves! works

Answer (score 3):

I added this post later as I ran into problems with my previous solution when I needed to pass cookies from multiple subdomains to a single API domain using AJAX and PHP

This was the challenge and solution:

1 - Backend PHP on api.example.com.

2 - Multiple JS front ends such as one.example.com, two.example.com etc.

3 - Cookies needed to be passed both ways.

4 - AJAX call from multiple front-ends to PHP backend on api.example.com

5 - In PHP, I do not prefer to use $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"], not always reliable/safe in my opinion (I had some browsers where HTTP-ORIGIN was always empty).

The normal way to do this in PHP with single front end domain is starting PHP code with:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://one.example.com');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

And in JS on one.example.com domain:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    cache: false,
    headers: "",
    data: myCallJSONStr,
    success: function(myResponse) {.....}
```

However, this is not workable as I am using multiple subdomains to call my API domain.

And this solution will **NOT work** as I want to pass on cookies:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

It conflicts with the pass on cookie setting on the JS site:

```
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
```

Here is what I did:

1 - use GET parameter to pass the Subdomain.

2 - Hardcode the Main domain in PHP so only (all) Subdomains are allowed.

This is the JS/JQuery AJAX part of my solution:

function getSubDomain(){

```
let mySubDomain = "";

let myDomain = window.location.host;
let myArrayParts = myDomain.split(".");
if (myArrayParts.length == 3){
    mySubDomain = myArrayParts[0];
}

return mySubDomain;
```

}

And in the AJAX call:

```
let mySubDomain = getSubDomain();
if (mySubDomain != ""){
    myURL += "?source=" + mySubDomain + "&end"; //use & instead of ? if URL already has GET parameters
}

jQuery.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    cache: false,
    headers: "",
    data: myCallJSONStr,
    success: function(myResponse) {.....}
```

Finally, the PHP part:

```
<?php

$myDomain = "example.com";
$mySubdomain = "";

if (isset($_GET["source"])) {
    $mySubdomain = $_GET["source"].".";
}

$myDomainAllowOrigin = "https://".$mySubdomain.$myDomain;
$myAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ".$myDomainAllowOrigin;

//echo $myAllowOrigin;

header($myAllowOrigin);  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

**IMPORTANT**, don't forget to set the cookies for all subdomains, in this case the domain for the cookie would be: .example.com (so with a dot in front of the main domain):

```
<?php

    //////////////// GLOBALS /////////////////////////////////
    
    $gCookieDomain = ".example.com";
    $gCookieValidForDays = 90;
    
    //////////////// COOKIE FUNTIONS /////////////////////////////////
    
    function setAPCookie($myCookieName, $myCookieValue, $myHttponly){
        global $gCookieDomain;
        global $gCookieValidForDays;
        
        $myExpires = time()+60*60*24*$gCookieValidForDays;
        setcookie($myCookieName, $myCookieValue, $myExpires, "/", $gCookieDomain, true, $myHttponly);   
        
        return $myExpires;
    }
```

This solution allows me to call the API on api.example.com from any subdomains on example.com.

NB. for situation where there is only a single calling subdomain, I prefer using .htaccess for setting CORS instead of PHP. Here is an example of .htaccess (linux/apache) for only one.example.com calling api.example.com:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://one.example.com"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</IfModule>
```

And place this .htaccess in the root of api.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct answer of Alexandre, this is my working CORS setting via .htaccess.

Added to .htaccess file on api.example.com in the directory with the phps (or above):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</IfModule>
```

And on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), I added to my AJAX call xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}. Here are all the settings:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    cache: false,
    headers: "",
    data: myCallJSONStr,
    success: function(myResponse) { etc....
```

Where URL makes a call to a php on api.example.com.

Please note that Alexandre is right, you must specify an exact subdomain, any wildcards unfortunately will not work. So this will NOT work:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This setting will be blocked by CORS when using the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true" setting.