# Ajax Call From Subdomain

Tags: php, ajax, subdomain

I have folders

```
/ 
includes/class
ajax
m
```

m is my subdomain and i want to call ajax script ajax/delete_cart.php from includes/class/class.cart.php. In fact i can call from my root typing like "ajax/delete_cart.php"

But the problem is subdomain. I tried to do like this "../ajax/delete_cart.php" but it is not working. What should i do ? I read about cross domain ([Setting a cookie on a subdomain from an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002038/setting-a-cookie-on-a-subdomain-from-an-ajax-request)) But it is not clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't know about the directory structure of your server. If your URL is on a different hostname, then you need to include that in the URL

```
//m.subdomain.example.com/ajax/delete_cart.php
```

This will be subject to [the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).