# How to get the Cookie of different domain in a web browser using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http, cookies

I have one web application running two different domain like example.com and test.example.com.I have created a cookie for example.com.I have seen in Firefox that the browser create a folder named "example.com" which contain the  cookie .But when I go through test.example.com it create a new cookie folder named "test.example.com" .Does it possible to get the cookie of "example.com" folder in "test.example.com" folder (I mean when I go through "test.example.com" if the cookie exists in "example.com"). Please let me know if there is any way.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You mean through the file system? This is not clear at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing cookies across different domains and different applications (classic ASP and ASP.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781353/sharing-cookies-across-different-domains-and-different-applications-classic-asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the other way around.  Create the `test.example.com` cookie using the `.example.com` domain.

see: [Can subdomain.example.com set a cookie that can be read by example.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089199/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com)