# Agiletoolkit login cookie issue on subdomains

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain, atk4, agiletoolkit

i am using the atk4 basic auth so when i login here `http://subdomain1.DOMAIN.pk/index.html`

i see all the details

```
you are visiting: subdomain1
your site : subdomain2

This is not your site string(23) "abc@gmail.com" You are logged in as :abc@gmail.com
```

then i visit this
`http://subdomain2.DOMAIN.pk/login.html`

it redirects me to login

but i already logged in at http://subdomain1.DOMAIN.pk/index.html

is subdomain affecting the cookies ?

Here is my code:

```
        $this->add('BasicAuth');
        $this->auth->setModel('User');
        //if site is a user site
        if ($this->api->skin != 'default' && !$this->auth->isLoggedIn()) { // && $this->privacy == $this->PRIVATE) {

            if(!$this->auth->isPageAllowed($this->page)){
                $this->auth->check();

            }
            echo 'you are visiting: '. $this->api->siteName;
            //echo $this->api->siteName;

            $m = $this->add('Model_Site');

            $tm = $m->loadBy('user_id', $this->auth->get('id'));
            $this->mySite = $tm->get('name');
            //->ref($this->auth->get('id'));
            echo '<br/>';
            echo 'your site : '. $this->mySite;

            echo '<br/>';

            if ($this->siteName == $this->mySite) {
                echo 'This is your site';
            } else {
                echo 'This is not your site';
            }

            //var_dump($this->auth->get('siteName'));

           // var_dump($this->auth->model->ref('theme_id')->get('name'));
            //if ($this->auth->get('sitename', skinName))
        }

        //maindomain
        if ($this->api->skin == 'default') {
            $this->add('BasicAuth');
            $this->auth->allowPage('index');
            $this->auth->allowPage('signup');
            $this->auth->setModel('User');

            if(!$this->auth->isPageAllowed($this->page)){
                $this->auth->check();




            }
        }
```

I saw some stackoverflow posts related to this topic. I wonder how i can solve it in atk4.

Here are the links:

- [Can subdomain.example.com set a cookie that can be read by example.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089199/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com)
- [Cookies and subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108558/cookies-and-subdomains?lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to tackle this issue in agiletoolkit is by adding this one line in config:

```
$config['session']['domain'] = '.DOMAIN.pk';
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the 'path' parameter for the cookie
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Probably you need to specify it.

Comment: yep, that is a solution but. Much simpler is to add $config['session']['domain'] = '.DOMAIN.pk'; in config.