# cross subdomain login with cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, authentication, subdomain

I have some sites in subdomains which are made in wordpress and some are made in codeigniter framework. System is already made and they have their own database. I have to created a common login system for all subdomains.

Do anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save login information into cookies and share it between subdomains.

See Cookies and subdomains:
[Cookies and subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108558/cookies-and-subdomains)