# .NET Single Sign On no longer works after moving website to another server

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, iis-6, single-sign-on

I have two websites hosted on the same server (IIS6 on Windows Server 2003 R2).
URL for the first website is www.domainname.com URL for the second website is my.domainname.com/website2 where "website2" is a virtual directory under "my" website on the same server.
I have configured Single Sign On using forms authentication on both sites and it was working very well. After I moved the first website to another server (IIS7 - Windows Server 2008 R2) SSO stopped working (both ways).

- "machineKey" and "forms" values are identical on both sites (see below).
- I can see that the ticket is passed from the server logs.
- I get the "Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid." error on the Event Viewer.
- both sites use .net 4

------- Configuration start

```
<machineKey validationKey="key1" decryptionKey="key2" decryption="3DES" validation="SHA1" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms requireSSL="true" name="domainnameAuth" domain=".domainname.com" loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="20" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

What am I missing here?
Any help on how to debug this situation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you may need that `path="/"` element too, although that should be the default.

Comment: Thanks Henk - I tried that before with no luck. (I edited the code above to include path)

Comment: On the first read I missed those `www` and `my` subdomains. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/108569/60761) you need `domain=".domainname.com"`

Comment: I changed the domain to     ".domainname.com" but it didn't help. Thanks!

Comment: And you restarted the server(s) and everything?

Comment: I only recycled the application pools. Do I need a full restart for this?

Comment: No, a recycle should be enough. Otoh you don't want to take the risk it isn't.

Comment: Can you share other cookies between the sites?

Comment: Yes, I can share an un-encrypted cookies between sites.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas about cookies. Do check the membership provider settings, it has an AppName setting too somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The issue disappeared after installing update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2656351

I beleive there was an issue with FormsAuthentication.Decrypt/Encrypt and that was fixed after this update.

Thank you for your help Henk!

Comment: I had the same issue. But after reading this post and running the security updates for .net 4, everything worked fine. Thanks!